# R - reading large file without loading into memory using chunked - warnings and errors

Tags: r, bigdata, chunked

I am trying to import a large SAS dataset (75.5 million rows, sas7bdat) into RStudio in a way in which I can work with the whole dataset.  After doing some digging and talking to some people it sounds like what I want to do is read in the file without loading it into memory, which is why I was attempting to use `chunked::read_csv_chunkwise` as this suggests:

https://mnoorfawi.github.io/handling-big-files-with-R/

I used SAS to export the dataset as a csv file. `v8_mc.csv`.  Then in R:

```
library(chunked)
library(dplyr)
## Here we don't read the file, we just get something like a pointer to it.
data_chunked <- read_csv_chunkwise("B:/SAS_DATASETS/v8_mc.csv",
                                   skip = 1,stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                                   header = TRUE,sep = ",")
```

But I get the following warning:

```
In FUN(X[[i]], ...) : Unsupported type 'logical'; using default type 'string'
```

The documentation said that `head()` should work with the chunked object, so I said what the heck and tried:

```
> head(data_chunked)
Error in .local(x, ...) : 
  Conversion to int failed; line=957; column=52; string='V061'
```

I've never used SAS before and I'm a total newb to big data in R. Since I can't open the sas or csv file in R, I can't figure out how to make a reproducible example. I'd welcome help to make this a better question.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `fread` from package `data.table`?

Comment: @SweepyDodo Yes, I tried 
`mc <- data.table::fread("B:/SAS_DATASETS/v8_mc.csv")
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 657.5 Mb`

Comment: Try `readr::read_csv` or  `vroom::vroom`.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck I tried
`vroom::vroom( "F:/APCD new PHA only/SAS_DATASETS/v8_medicalClaims.csv",
              .name_repair = ~ janitor::make_clean_names(., case = "lower_camel"))`
indexed 2.15GB in  8m, 51.03MB/s 
but the file is 50GB and it is taking 8 min for under 3GB.  Is that reasonable? Will R be able to work with that without chunking it or using sqlite?

Comment: @abra My concern is that even if you used [batch query](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSQLite/vignettes/RSQLite.html) the same problem will persist. The problem is your local machine (pc/mac) not having enough memory
I recently wanted to feed in a large csv into R to no avail. Same error `cannot allocate vector of size...`. csv was about 4 GB zipped (can't remember exact size when unzipped, easily doubled. Larger still when fed into R)

This memory isn't exclusive to R. Same will happen with Pandas/Python. We are limited by local RAM

Comment: I have also tried packages `ff` and `bigmemory`. However, they did not offer the flexibility of dataframes (or `data.table`) as they are matrix based. Furthermore, they actually managed to import less data compared to `data.table` before running out of memory.
I suppose this is when cloud computing is necessary. From my experience of R server (virtual machine)100 m rows is more than manageable (tho I believe also depends on the server/package one is paying)
Nonetheless, I hope to hear from others for solutions

Comment: p.s. my machine (lap top) has 16GB RAM (not great). The 4GB zipped csv I mentioned had about 214 million rows

Comment: @SweepyDodo I'm actually connected via VPN and Remote Desktop Connection, to a server that supposedly has 128GB usable RAM.  I think what I want to do is read in the file without loading the whole thing into memory, which is why I was attempting to use `chunked` as this suggests:
https://mnoorfawi.github.io/handling-big-files-with-R/